The operating system freezes immediately after starting
I have a Gigabyte G5 KF laptop with two operating systems, Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. After selecting the system in GRUB, the system boots, but immediately freezes. The problem started after I booted Ubuntu 24.04 from a USB drive. It looked like this: after booting Ubuntu 24.04 from USB, a window appeared with the option to install the system, I closed it, saw that there was an option to continue working with Ubuntu, and then I turned off Ubuntu.
Then I wanted to boot the installed Windows 11, which I could not do anymore. It only shows a black screen with the Gigabyte logo. In the case of the second installed system, which is Ubuntu 22.04, I only see a black screen.
I thought that some options in the BIOS might have changed, so I restored the BIOS to default settings. When that didn't help I wanted to try reinstalling the Ubuntu 22.04 system from USB, but just like in the case of the already installed system, only a black screen is displayed.
How can I get the systems to start?

Sorry but your question is not making much sense. As well there is no actual detail here that can be used to offer any help. Why did you boot from a USB Media of Ubuntu 24.04? What was the other system you tried to boot and why? Reset the BIOS from what to what and why? Why would reinstalling not help? Reinstalling what? As you can see there are a lot of unanswered issues before anyone can offer help.

I tried booting Ubuntu 24.04 from a USB drive because I wanted to learn how to boot the system in live mode from USB. After I started it, a window appeared with the option to install the system, I closed it, saw that there was an option to continue working with Ubuntu and then turned Ubuntu off.

After finishing this attempt, I wanted to boot the installed Windows 11, which I could not do anymore. It only shows a black screen with the gigabyte logo. In the case of the second installed system, which is Ubuntu 22.04, I only see a black screen. I thought that some options in the BIOS might have changed so I restored the BIOS to default settings. When that didn't help I wanted to try reinstalling the Ubuntu 22.04 system from USB but just like in the case of the already installed system, only a black screen is displayed.

Not as comments but add the info to the question with edit. Comments go away after a while.
